# CPanel for web server

Tags: cpanel

I am using a web-based server (Hostgator).  When I run scripts and queries using CPanel, does speed/performance purely depend on the remote server I use or is it also affected by the speed of my local computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it purely depends on server performance, once query is fired and it reaches server. performance is also affected by your internet speed but that is too low impact.

it also depends on the query cost, which is affected by your database design/data hence you should consider all these factors if you see the performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Server performance is the key factor since all the commands you typing are executed on the server. 
You can see server resources from **server performance**  link in the cPanel.